# How to change a div using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've looked around a lot for this but I still can't find an answer.

I want to change a div's content by checking whether a cookie is set. The div's content varies between:

1) `<a href="login/index.php"><img src="images/buttons/login_register.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/login_register_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/login_register.png'" alt="Login / Register"></img></a>`

2) `<a href="login/logout.php"><img src="images/buttons/logout.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/logout_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/logout.png'" alt="Logout"></img></a>`

Now when I do: `document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = ""` it doesn't work because it thinks the double quote marks used inside the HTML belong to it, is there any way that I can achieve this change? I know how to get the cookie etc, I just need to change the div, thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = '<a href="login/logout.php"><img src="images/buttons/logout.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/logout_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/logout.png'" alt="Logout"></img></a>';

Comment: i'll test that, one sec

Comment: Wait, you'll need to escape the single-quotes inside then too...

Comment: doesn't work, it just does the same as the double quote

Comment: document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = '<a href="login/logout.php"><img src="images/buttons/logout.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'images/buttons/logout_hover.png\'" onmouseout="this.src=\'images/buttons/logout.png\'" alt="Logout"></img></a>'; sry! escape '

Comment: works, thanks :) can you make it an answer?